# Setting combobox option length in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a way in jQuery to access the options length of a combobox?

I'm trying to change this line

```
cmbBox.options.length = 0;
```

with a jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use jQuery's [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

```
$('#cmbBox').prop('options').length = 0
```

But Jacob is right in saying that you shouldn't always use jQuery for everything.

Consider this solution instead:

```
$('#cmbBox')[0].options.length = 0
```

You get a shorter CSS selector syntax to select the element (rather than document.getElementById), but you end up using the same native JavaScript syntax solution.